# Update a cell and return PDF file of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sXSWMQfPkkwDS4lsSpnV2y54lhKFpdeY8brqyGtuc_k/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet that is of 2 sheets, Data nd Report.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var DATA_SHEET = "Data";
  var REPORT_SHEET = "Report";
  var FILE_Id = "1sXSWMQfPkkwDS4lsSpnV2y54lhKFpdeY8brqyGtuc_k";
  // Prevent concurrent access overwritting data
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  // As we are passing JSON in the body, we need to unpairse it
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
  //  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
    var report = doc.getSheetByName(REPORT_SHEET);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var nextRow = lastRow + 1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    if(lastRow < 10){
      RefID = "PRF.00" + lastRow
    } else {
      if(lastRow < 100){
        RefID = "PRF..0" + lastRow
      } else {
        RefID = "PRF.." + lastRow
      }
    }
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Ref"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column

        row.push(RefID);
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
         row.push(new Date());
        } else { // else use header name to get data
          row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
       }
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    /*********************************************/
    // report.getRange("D4").setValue(RefID);
    // Need to create the PDF here and send it back to the client
    /*********************************************/
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

The `Report` sheet looks like this:
[image]

And the `Data` sheet looks like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is:

1. [Done] Receiving data from client and post in the `Data` sheet, with assigning `RefID` and `Timestamp` which is done correctly.
2. [Done] Update the data in the merged cells (D4:F4) at the `Report` sheet with the latest `RefID` that had been added, I worked it with`report.getRange("D4").setValue(RefID);`
3. [No idea how to make it] Once step 2 is done, some `vlookup` statements are working at the `Report` sheet, I want to generate a `PDF` from this sheet and send it back to the client.

**UPDATE**
I tried this to get the PDF, but did not work, it created copy of the sheet, but failed in converting the vlookup merged cells into text, and failed to generate the pdf file:

```
function printPDF() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
  var sourceSheet = file.getSheetByName(REPORT_SHEET);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_Id);
  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(FILE_Id).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != REPORT_SHEET){
    destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  //replace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,20,8);
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, 20, 8);
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  //save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(REPORT);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If you want to make the additional script of `printPDF()` work correctly, please put `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before the blob is retrieved from Spreadsheet.
- In the case of the Google Docs (Document, Spreadsheet and Slides), when the blob is retrieved from the file, the format is automatically changed to PDF format. It seems that this is the current specification.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(REPORT);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
```

To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // Added
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().setName(REPORT);  // Modified. This is the same with destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(REPORT)
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
```

Then your full code be as:

```
function printPDF(RefID) {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
  var sourceSheet = file.getSheetByName(REPORT_SHEET);
  sourceSheet.getRange("D4").setValue(RefID);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_Id);
  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(FILE_Id).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))
  // Copy sheet data into values to avoid reference issues
  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(REPORT_SHEET);
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != REPORT_SHEET){
    destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
  //save to pdf
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // Added
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().setName(REPORT);  // Modified. This is the same with 
 // destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(REPORT)
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Answer (score 0):

`getBlob().getAs('application/pdf')` will not work. You need to use a Google API for converting a sheet to PDF.

You need to do something along the following lines:

```js
const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${FILE_Id}/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf`;
const options = {
  headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
      }
};
const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).setName(`${REPORT}`);
```